# Why does my If statement not change my integer variable in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm new to VBA and trying to resolve this error regarding the IF statement. I'm trying to change my integer variable to 3 depending on my Activesheet cell value which is currently typed FALSE.

```
Sub IFStatement() 
Dim w as integer 

w = 0  
If Activesheet.cells(58, 11).value = "FALSE" 
Then   w = 3
End If 
MsgBox w
End sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `.value = False` as you want to compare against a boolean value not a string containing the word False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The If Statement

[If...Then...Else statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub IFStatement()
    
    Dim w As Long
    ' w = 0 ' is redundant because its initial value is 0 (when declared).
    
    ' 1 line
    
    ' If it is a boolean:
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(58, 11).Value = False Then w = 3
    'If CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(58, 11).Value) = "FALSE" Then w = 3
    ' Case-insensitive
    'If StrComp(CStr(ActiveSheet.Cells(58, 11).Value), "FaLSe", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then w = 3
    
    ' If it is a string ('FALSE):
    'If ActiveSheet.Cells(58, 11).Value = "FALSE" Then w = 3
    ' Case-insensitive
    'If StrComp(ActiveSheet.Cells(58, 11).Value, "FaLSe", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then w = 3
    
     
    ' 3 lines Another way to write the If statement:

'    If ActiveSheet.Cells(58, 11).Value = False Then ' finishes with 'Then'
'        w = 3
'    End If
    
    MsgBox w

End Sub
```